# Does the Performance Wizard exist only in the Visual Studio Team System version?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

<strike>I guess you already know the question ;)</strike>

Does the performance wizard only exist in the Visual Studio Team System version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Team System Development Edition** and in **Team System Team Suite**.